# Who is Goddess Ishani?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, goddess

I have heard about a goddess named "Ishani" and i want to know about this form of Devi. But, Who is Goddess Ishani and Is any scriptures mentioned about this goddess ?

Comment: Bhagawan Shiva is Ishana and Mata Parvati is Ishani.

Comment: Sounds like the female verison of Ishaana who is Shiva, so my guess is Parvati.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ishani is the name of Devi Adishakti. It is mentioned in the Puranas.

Also, the goddess called Ishani is stated in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226053.html) of Shiva Purana.

> 11-12. Mahākālī went ahead for the destruction of Dakṣa accompanied by nine Durgās Viz:—Kālī, Kātyāyanī, **Īśānī**, Cāmuṇḍā, Muṇḍamardinī, Bhadrakālī, Bhadrā, Tvaritā and Vaiṣṇavī and the goblins.

She also mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/lalitopakhyana-lalita-mahatmya/d/doc362986.html) of Lalitopakhyana.

> 84b-89. The following are the Śaktis[12] of the letters grouped in different classes. The following (?) sixteen Śaktis (are concerned with vowels, their names being with those very vowels except in certain cases). They are Amṛtā, Ānandinī, Indrāṇī, **Īśānī**, Umā, Ūrddhvakeśī, Ṛdviduṣī, Lṛkārikā, Ekapādātmikā, Aiśvaryakāriṇī, Auṣadhātmikā, Ambikā and Rakṣātmikā

In 2nd chapter from 10th Canto of Bhagavata Purana, Krishna says Yogamaya worshipped by people in diffrent forms.

> 11-12. People will erect temples for you on the earth and will designate you with various names such as Durgā, Bhadrakālī, Vijayā, Vaiṣṇavī, Kumudā, Caṇḍikā, Kṛṣṇā, Mādhavī, Kanyakā, Māyā, Nārāyaṇī, **Īśānī**, Śāradā and Ambika.

Answer (score 1):

Hindu goddess Durga or Parvti; consort of Lord Shiva.

On the baby names site, it is listed as below [Ishani meaning and origin](https://www.thebump.com/b/ishani-baby-name)

> Meaning:Desire; Goddess Durga, Parvati
> Ishani is the feminine form of Ishan and of Indian origin, meaning “desire.” It is also the name given to the Hindu goddess Durga or Parvati, the wife of Lord Shiva. An incredibly powerful deity, goddess Durga is greatly venerated among Indian divinities. She is considered multi-dimensional, with many associations, including strength, protection, motherhood, war, and destruction. Such a significant figure will inspire baby Ishani to take on the world, paving their own path as they succeed in their endeavors.

Comment: This is not an authentic source. Please provide authentic source like Itihasa, Purana agama or tantra texts to support your answer.